# Sample size calculation

Tags: statistics

A biologist is planning a study to estimate the proportion of elk in British Columbia that are infected with a bacterial pathogen. He came up with a nifty scheme to obtain blood samples from a simple random sample of animals in the target population. The biologist agree in wanting an estimate of the percent infected that is accurate to within plus or minus four percentage points (or less), nineteen times out of twenty. The biologist is wedded to the notion that the sample size determination should incorporate generally accepted belief in the research community. In particular, it is believed that somewhere between 15% and 35% of this elk population are infected. And it is believed that the size of this population is between 1100 and 2300.

What sample size should the biologist recommend for this study?

How can I obtain the correct percentage between 15% and 35% ? I am thinking to use $0.02 = 1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ to find $n.$ Or, should I find $n$ for each of 1100, 2300, 35% and 15% and take their average?

Answer (score 0):

The way the problem is worded, I think you need
$$0.04 = 1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$$
You are being asked to fix the margin of error, not the
total length of the confidence interval.

Try $p = .15$ and $p =.35$ and solve for $n$ in
each case. Roughly, I got $n \approx 300$ and $550$,
respectively. Those numbers are more than 10% of
the estimated herd sizes (1100 and 2300).

That leads me to believe you need a finite population
correction, which means repeating the computation of $n$
with a different formula. See if you have such a formula
in your text. (The result would be to make the variability
a little smaller, and thus the required sample sizes
somewhat smaller.)

Comment: We have such a formula. fpc = sqrt(N-n/N-1). What should I do with it? Should I take the average of the two FPCs?

Comment: I got 235 and 451, should I take the average?

Comment: If this is a hwk problem, they probably want the max sample size as the answer.Notice that variance is largest for estimated p nearest 1/2 and for smaller estimated herd size; larger variance leads to larger required sample size for given margin of error. If this were a real-life study I'd use speculated values of p to get a Bayesian prior and sample  animals sequentially in small batches until Bayesian posterior probability interval becomes short enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use an *ad hoc* procedure to decide what the sample size should be.  Averaging different sample sizes is not a good idea.

In the case where observations are made on a negligible number of random trials relative to the size of the population, the standard deviation of a binomial distribution is a reasonable assumption for getting the standard error of the sample proportion.

But in practice, if the population from which the sample is to be drawn is small relative to the sample size, and the sampling occurs without replacement, then the binomial model may not be appropriate.  Instead, a hypergeometric model would be needed.

If we believe that the population from which the sample of size $n$ is to be drawn has a size of $m$, and we also believe that the number of infected animals is $d = \theta m$ where $\theta$ is somewhere between $0.15$ and $0.35$, then the variance of the number $X$ of infected animals found in the sample is $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = n \frac{d}{m} \frac{m-d}{m} \frac{m-n}{m-1} = \theta(1-\theta) \frac{n(m-n)}{m-1}.$$    Thus the standard error of the sample proportion $\hat p = X/n$ of infected animals is $$\operatorname{SE}(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n} \frac{m-n}{m-1}}.$$  Notice that this is exactly the binomial model with the finite population correction factor $\sqrt{(m-n)/(m-1)}$ (I wrote $m$ instead of your $N$).  Hence for a margin of error for a Wald-type (normal approximation) confidence interval of $$\operatorname{ME} = z_{0.025}^* \operatorname{SE}(\hat p) \approx 1.96 \operatorname{SE}(\hat p) = 0.04,$$ we require $$\theta (1-\theta) \frac{m-n}{n(m-1)} \approx 0.000416508.$$  Solving for $n$ in terms of $m$, $\theta$ yields $$n = \frac{m\theta(1-\theta)}{0.000416508(m-1) + \theta(1-\theta)}.$$  This expression is an increasing function for $m > 1$, meaning that the required sample size $n$ gets larger as the assumed population size is larger.   And it is also increasing on the interval $\theta \in [0.15, 0.35]$, so we conclude that the most conservative sample size that gives at least 95% coverage probability under all hypothesized scenarios of $m$ and $\theta$ corresponds to the choice $m = 2300$, $\theta = 0.35$, with value $n = 442$.

This is smaller than the non-corrected value of $n = 547$.  And at the other extreme, the least conservative (most optimistic) sample size corresponds to the choice $m = 1100$, $\theta = 0.15$, with only $n = 240$ required.